# Self-referencing a partial key of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, self-reference

I am designing a datatable (-s) for storing the list of shareholders. In case a shareholder is a nominee, it discloses the list of share owners. These all need to have a pile of similar references. Thus, I would like to store all in one table. Nominees are registered shareholders and thus, they have an account number in the system, from which I get the data. Opposed to this, share owners that are coming from nominee disclosure have no their own account number, and share account number of the nominee.

I add a uniquifier to the table. I would like to assume that all registered shareholders and the nominees have 0 in this field. The disclosure list (non-registered share owners, that work via the nominee) have a value above zero in this uniquifier filed. Basically, a numbered list.

I need to know the nominee, to whom this disclosed share owner belongs. So, we are coming to a self-reference. It could be Ok, if not for the uniquifier field. It is illegal to make a foreign key on part of a primary key and assume that there is zero in the uniquifier field. So, could you please suggest a walkthrough.

To better explain, here is the excerpt:

```
Create Table Account (
  AccountId Int,
  Uniquifier Int,

  NomineeId Int,

  Constraint PK$Account Primary Key (AccountId, Uniquifier)     
)
```

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
Alter Table Account 
  Add Constraint FK$SelfReference Foreign Key (NomineeId) References Account (AccountId)
```

which is illegal, since

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Account' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK$SelfReference'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, I can do 

`
Alter Table Account Add AlwaysZero Int Null; 
Alter Table Account 
  Add Constraint FK$SelfReferenceWierd Foreign Key (NomineeId, AlwaysZero) References Account (AccountId, Uniquifier)
` and add an artificial field, that will always contain 0 by referencing a row, that on assumption, will always have 0 in Uniquifier column. Of course, I can even add some Check constraints for that, but this look wierd for me, and there should be better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which will be `0` when the FK ought to be enforced and `NULL` otherwise. This can then be used in the foreign key reference:

```
Create Table Account (
  AccountId Int,
  Uniquifier Int,

  NomineeId Int,
  NomineeXRef as CASE WHEN Uniqueifier > 0 THEN 0 END persisted

  Constraint PK$Account Primary Key (AccountId, Uniquifier),
  Constraint FK$SelfReference Foreign Key (NomineeId,NomineeXRef) References Account (AccountId, Uniquifier)     
)
```

Comment: Looks elegant. I removed NomineeId and used AccountId instead for the FK. Plus a check constraint for NomineeXRef, which will be forced to be either 0 or NULL, should handle the task.

Comment: Sorry, the Check is unnecessary, since the calculated column cannot return anything else other than 0 or Null. Thank you!