# EF Code First Self-Referencing Composite Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I’m making a EF code first MVC model to store articles.

Each article can have multiple pages, so I have made the key a composite key of an ID plus a page number.

I also want articles to have sub-articles, so I want articles to self-reference themselves with a foreign key.

As the key is a composite key I’m struggling with the self-referencing. When I scaffold the model and attempt to use the controls I get 'System.StackOverflowException'

```
public class Article
    {

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int ArticlePageNo { get; set; }

        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

        public string ArticleBody { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ArticleID, ArticlePageNo")]
        public Article ArticleParent { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why have a composite key that references itself? Can you store an article and it's pages seperately. Or to articles require a reference to itself as well?

Comment: I want articles to have parent and child articles, so that will require a self referencing. I also want paged articles using a composite key. That's why I require a composite key that references itself.

Comment: Storing the pages separately is something I will consider if I cant get it to work this way.

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693269/self-referencing-a-partial-key-of-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

I do think that you're not using EF properly, in this case.
If I understand corectly your code, EF will try to reference the object to itself and, if you're using an eager loading scenario, that will result in a Stackoverflow exception. So you are actually defining a 1 to 1 relationship between the Article and Article, specifying both the primary key and the foreign key as a composite key formed from ArticleID and ArticlePageNo. Not a thing EF can digest.
I would suggest you remodel your data: so you have an one to many relationship between article and page, and a one to many relationship between article and article. The code would look somehing like this:

```
public class Article
{
    // object unique ID
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // parent Id used as foreign key
    public int? ParentArticleId { get; set; }
    // navigational property for parent
    public virtual Article ParentArticle { get; set; }
    // navigational property for children
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    // navigational property for article pages
    public virtual ICollection<ArticlePage> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class ArticlePage 
{
    // object unique ID
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PageBody { get; set; }

    // parent Id used as foreign key
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    // navigational property for parent article
    public virtual Article { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This model achieves what I was attempting to do but following the feedback I may rethink my approach.

```
public class Article
{

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ArticlePageNo { get; set; }

    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    public string ArticleBody { get; set; }

    public int? ParentArticleID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentArticlePageNo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentArticleID,ParentArticlePageNo")]
    public virtual Article ArticleParent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

}
```